# Add css via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hy, its maybe a stupid question and tottaly easy, but I can't make it work so please help. Here's the code.

```
asp=height / width * 100;
document.getElementById("head_wrap").style["padding-top"] = "'+asp+%'";
```

using alert(asp); gives the correct value, but I made some mistake here "'+asp+%'", I want the value to be in percentages but as I said It doesn't work. 
thanks for your help!

Comment: The value is fine. The CSS property is wrong. It's `paddingTop`...

Comment: The value is also wrong because of quoting problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in the set value with double quotes and single quotes. You also could use a  property from [`style`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) object, for sample:

```
asp = height / width * 100;
document.getElementById("head_wrap").style.paddingTop = asp + "%";
```

Alternativally, you could use as you did, but with some adjusts in your code.

```
asp = height / width * 100;
document.getElementById("head_wrap").style["padding-top"] = asp + "%;
```

I modified your `jsfiddle`, take a [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/weebq7Lw/).

### See Also

- [List of properties supported by `style` object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)
- [HTMLElement.Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work the padding isn't added to the css of the element.here's the fiddle for better understanding what i want http://jsfiddle.net/hLp8g73n/ basically to mantain aspect ratio of backg. image and apply it to the parent div.

Comment: This is the syntax provided by javascript, make sure your DOM is right ot accept it. You also could try using pixels `px` instead `%`.

Comment: @TaoByebye: Your jsFiddle doesn't contain an element with ID `head_wrap`, so it can't work. Also, you are binding the `window.onload` handler after the the pages was already loaded, so it's not even triggered.

Comment: so what do you suggest instead to fix this window.onload  problem

Comment: @TaoByebye: Either remove `window.onload = function() { .... };` or set up the jsFiddle to run the script after the DOM is ready (you know, left hand column, `no wrap - in <body>`